# PHP - How can mysql_fetch_array give me selected returns?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So basically, i'm trying to make some sort of timeline with the post of my users, that gives me the posts of all users ordered by time. But instead, gives me the following:

```
*User1  'post1',
 User1  'post2',
 User1  'post3'..

*User2  'post1',
 User2  'post2',
 User2  'post3'..
```

---

I want all the post ordered instead of all the posts from user1 then all the posts from user2, etc. Well i hope it made sense thank you guys.

**The query**

```
  <?php
$varq1 = mysql_query('SELECT id2 FROM followers WHERE id ="'.$_SESSION['id'].'"');
    while($req5 = mysql_fetch_array($varq1)){

$req9=$req5['id2'];
$nsql = mysql_query('SELECT content, id, profile_id FROM contenido WHERE profile_id in("'.$req9.'") order by content_time desc');**strong text**
while($nrow = mysql_fetch_array($nsql)){    
?>
```

**The HTML/ php call**

```
<div class="divider">
<center><?php echo  "".$nrow['content'].""; ?><center/>
</div>
```

Comment: I really hope you've escaped everything you've put into that query with `mysql_real_escape_string`. There's a reason `mysql_query` is deprecated and should not be used in new applications, and it's that the interface is dangerous by default, prone to [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/php) of the worst kind.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: ok thank you guys, really informative stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do both queries in a single one ... giving you the ability to sort by time

```
select content,id, profile_id from contenido where profile_id in (SELECT id2 FROM followers WHERE id ="'.$_SESSION['id'].'") order by content_time desc
```

fetch that and you will have exactly what you want :) all the posts from different users sorted by time.

Comment: omg it worked, thank you!! sorry i can't give you a vote up, it says i need 15 rep, and this is my first question.

Comment: @Aaron , That's why you can accept the answer instead(do this by clicking the outlined checkmark under the down arrow).  It gives more rep anyway.

Comment: Alright, but quick follow up question, what if i want to include the 'pictures' from another table into that query that you provided, lets say: mysql_query("SELECT reference,description FROM user_photos WHERE`profile_id`='".$row['id']."' order by id desc");

Comment: In the above code i meant "order by time_pic". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: sorry for the late replay "i was sleeping :)" anyway its easy all you have to do is join 2 tables together.. in this way 

select contenido.content,contenido.id, contenido.profile_id from contenido join user_photos on contenido.profile_id = user_photos.profile_id where contenido.profile_id in (SELECT id2 FROM followers WHERE id ="'.$_SESSION['id'].'") order by contenido.content_time desc

Comment: @Karim Magdy Mansour. Thanks for the reply, but when i run that query returns duplicated results from the 2 tables like this, user1: post1,picture1,post1,picture1,post1,picture1,post2,picture2, etc basically gives me 3 of the same before passing to the next. Here's the query I'm using: mysql_query('select contenido.content,contenido.id, contenido.profile_id, user_photos.reference from contenido JOIN user_photos ON contenido.profile_id = user_photos.profile_id where contenido.profile_id in (SELECT id2 FROM followers WHERE id ="'.$_SESSION['id'].'") order by contenido.content_time desc ');

Comment: emm.. now am a little bit confused... what do you mean by user1: post 1, picture 1, post1, pciture1 etc...
your query does the following.. is select those columns "content, id , profile_id "from contenido table" and reference "from user_photos" from both the contenido table and the user_photos table where both rows have the same profile_id and that same profile id .. should be in the result of this query (SELECT id2 FROM followers WHERE id ="'.$_SESSION['id'].'") All the results are listed by the content_time from the contenido table in descending order.. anyway .. i just need more info :)

Comment: yeah,so in essence, selects the correct columns 'contenido.profile_id','contenido.content','contenido.id' and 'user_photos.reference' from the 2 different tables 'contenido' and 'user_photos' So far it's good, but later when i call the rows:  <div class="divider9"><?php  echo  "".$nrow['content'].""; ?><div/>  <div class="divider29">
<?php echo "<a href=\"profile.php?id=".$nrow['profile_id']."\">
  <img src=\"".$nrow['profile_id']."/pics/".$nrow['reference']."\"></a><br/>"; ?> </div> Gives me the correct info, and ordered right, but gives me replicated posts seems to be something with the Join

Comment: @Aaron okay i don't know the structure of the database.. but you can try this...   SELECT contenido.profile_id, contenido.id, contenido.content FROM contenido JOIN user_photos ON contenido.profile_id = user_photos.profile_id WHERE contenido.profile_id IN (SELECT id2 FROM followers WHERE id ="'.$_SESSION['id'].'") GROUP BY contenido.profile_id ORDER BY contenido.content_time DESC;

the above query will simply select group similar rows with the same profile_id "so only one will be displayed"

Answer (score 0):

```
'SELECT id2, content, c.id, profile_id
FROM followers f JOIN contenido c ON profile_id = id2
WHERE f.id = "'.$_SESSION['id']"'
ORDER BY content_time DESC, id2
```

Answer (score 0):

Plz Use This Code Then Check

```
<?php
$varq1 = mysql_query('SELECT id2 FROM followers WHERE id ="'.$_SESSION['id'].'"');
while($req5 = mysql_fetch_array($varq1)){

$req9=$req5['id2'];
$nsql = mysql_query('SELECT content, id, profile_id FROM contenido WHERE profile_id='".$req9."' order by content_time desc');/*strong text*/
while($nrow = mysql_fetch_array($nsql)){    
?>
<div class="divider">
   <center><?php  '". echo $nrow['content']."'; ?><center/>
</div>
```

Comment: It didn't work as i wanted, but i guess i forgot to include important details, anyways thanks.